# Problems with wired ethernet connection Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

After some partition shuffling, I've got a problem on my 11.10 system. The wired ethernet interface fails to come up, although the wireless interface is working.
I'm using NetworkManager. I thought this may be a problem with NetworkManager, so I checked the config files, which look ok. I then tried re-installing the package, but this didn't resolve the issues.
I'm not sure at this point if the problem is due to software configuration, or a hardware problem. I've also tried the cable in other router ports, but same problem.

The symptoms are:-

System settings -> Network reports that the cable is unplugged (it isn't)

ifconfig reports the following

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:4d:a2:a2:a7:fe  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:792 (792.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0xe000
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file has the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` file has the following:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
```

The router's red light is on for this port

`dmesg` reports:

```
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a problem with the driver. First figure out which driver you are using. On my system, for example, it's the e1000e driver. I can see the name "pci:e1000e" in the listing of /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver/module/drivers/. The driver name will appear in the module list obtained from the "lsmod" command. Search for this name in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux. If you don't find a bug report that describes your case then use apport-bug to open a new bug report against the "linux" package. Include the information above and make sure to say what Ethernet controller you have, as revealed by the lspci command.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it was a driver problem. I downloaded the official driver from the Realtek website, after looking at this page. Followed the instructions there and it solved my problem.
https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/

Thanks once again!

Comment: Also note that after a kernel update, you will have to follow the above procedure to insert the driver module into the kernel.